# How to list all REST URLs in Ruby on Rails commanline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I want to get list of all REST URLs in one of rails project. I think there is a command to get them.I am new to rails so no luck so far.

Thanks 
Smith

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rake routes` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

- open command prompt
- Navigate to project folder
- run `rake routes`